# Cypress global cy.fixture setup

Tags: cypress

I am looking way for a way to mock external images by URL. For example, I have a logo that is stored on `https://example.com/logo.png`. My goal is to load the logo from the fixtures folder instead of creating requests for the logo every test. I expect something like `cy.fixture('https://example.com/logo.png', '/logo.png'). I want to tell cypress to replace all logo requests to fixture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, then the below solution will do the trick

If you use a >= 6.0 Cypress version, you can set up a global request listener in the index file in the support folder.
It could look something like this:

```
cy.intercept('GET', 'https://example.com/logo.png', { fixture: 'logo.png' });
```

See the [official Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Arguments) on this